# how to remove a character from a list

Tags: python, list, char

I'm making a simple lottery game.

For instance, this is a sample randomized output from my lottery:

```
winning_num =  [1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Then this is the sample output from prompting the user to input 4 values:

```
guessed_num =  ['1', '2', '4', '3']
```

whenever i compare them it returns me False, obviously because they're different from each other. So I want to know how to remove the (') character in the guessed_num so it would be same and possibly give me a True.

I can't simply remove the (') char, I need a function to remove them.

Comment: @sushanth I think the problem is more than that, he doesn't understand the concept of types

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function returns a `string` of the user's input, meaning when you put the user's guesses into `guessed_num` you are making a list of `string` variables, so obviously they will not be equal to integer numbers. So you need to make it a number, like so:

```
   guessed_num = [int(i) for i in guessed_num]
```

Input: `guessed_num =  ['1', '2', '4', '3']`

Output: `guessed_num =  [1, 2, 4, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

You seems to not understand the nature of your content. The simple quote `'` is **not** part of your content, that simply indicate that your content is a `string`, whereas `5` without quotes (as display) is an `int`, a number

So what you need is a conversion

```
x = '5' # type str
x = 5   # type int
5 == int('5')
```

So

```
guessed_num = [int(i) for i in guessed_num]
```

Comment: Or ```list(map(int, guessed_num))``` but I don't think it will make any difference :)

Comment: no, it also comes with strings. so the guessed _num could be a list combination of int and str

Comment: @equinox_xy, So instead of converting guessed_num to integers, you can convert `winning_num` to a list as `winning_num = list(map(str, winning_num))`